# cv2 dnn_superres : OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/net_impl.cpp:1195: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I wanted to increase the quality of my single-channel image with text, but it crashes for me. I converted the image to 3-channel but it didn't help. How else can I change the image?

[image: text image]

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

img = cv2.imread("/content/test_image.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img2 = np.zeros_like(img)
img2[:,:,0] = gray
img2[:,:,1] = gray
img2[:,:,2] = gray
img2 = np.multiply(img2, 255.0/image.max() , out=img2, casting='unsafe')
img2.shape
print(img2.shape) ##(3508, 2481, 3)

sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()


path = "EDSR_x3.pb"
sr.readModel(path)
sr.setModel("edsr", 3)

result = sr.upsample(img2)
cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", result)
```

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-eb6e8677f733> in <module>
     16 
     17 # Upscale the image
---> 18 result = sr.upsample(image)
     19 
     20 # Save the image

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/net_impl.cpp:1195: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively(int, cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Net::Impl::LayersShapesMap&)'
>  (expected: 'total(os[i]) > 0'), where
>     'total(os[i])' is -2066910208
> must be greater than
>     '0' is 0
```

Comment: Please include your test image.

Comment: @stateMachine   attached the picture